# Applying CSS (a vertical line) to an iFrame from the parent document

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, iframe

I have an 'Export Text/PDF to Excel' functionality in my webapp. I display the original report in the same domain to be exported to excel in an iFrame inside a jsp(parent doc)

```
<iframe name="imgbox" id="imgbox" scrolling="yes" width="80%" height="400" src="/xxx/xx.txt" ></iframe>
```

In the existing page, I ask the users to click the positions/points inside the iFrame for column splitting i.e., the text between 2 selected split points form a column in the resultant excel sheet and I record the positions using jQuery's event.pageX. NOW WHERE I NEED HELP is that I want the selected positions to be highlighted by vertical, colored thin lines as a column marker from the top edge to the bottom edge of the iFrame

This is what I want:
[Click to view the resultant jsp page](http://i59.tinypic.com/73i0bn.jpg)

Some one please help!!!

Comment: You can't from the parent frame apply a style to the iframe itself or the content (assuming it a TXT file here and not an HTML document). You could apply a style to a DIV container around the iframe

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I just need the vertical lines from the top to bottom of the frame's edges. It would be fine if its of the DIV's but one thing i'm not sure is how to apply the css to div based on pixel position (i've the pixel positions available)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up positioning the elements over each other, the text file was a random file I selected from google. You will have to track the clicks but the hard part is done an the code could be a little cleaner but it answers your problem I hope.

Answer requires jQuery

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3aQC4/1/

```
<html><head>
<style>
#con, .line{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;    
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:300px;
    width:600px;
    border:1px solid black;
z-index:10;
    background-color:transparent;
}

.line{
    border:none;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    z-index:5;
}

iframe {
    position:absolute;    
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
    height:300px;
    width:600px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="con"></div>
  <iframe class="stack" src="http://textfiles.com/bbs/dljunkie.txt"></iframe>


<script>
$('#con').click(function(e){
var html='<div style="width:'+e.offsetX+'px;border:1px solid red" class="line"></div>';
$('body').append(html);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! Yeah I have the other parts like tracking the clicks n stuffs up & working. Was just waiting for this css stuff. Nice one :)

Comment: Oops! Mate, I couldn't fix my code with this. The 'con' DIV & my iframe and the resultant lines are all screwed up. Gist of the jsp page I posted earlier with your fix: http://jsfiddle.net/Chande07/jyXQY/3/